# Visual Basic 6: Run-time error 424 (If Function)

Tags: vb6, syntax-error, runtime-error

Sorry, I'm a beginner with VB6. I have this:

```
Private Sub Command5_Click()
    If MessageBox.Show("Sei sicuro di voler uscire?", "Sicuro?", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo) = DialogResult.Yes Then
        Unload Me
    End If
End Sub
```

But it returns an error:

```
Run-time error '424':
Object required
```

Please, may anyone answer my question?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`MessageBox.Show` and `MessageBoxButtons` are .NET things. (Why aren’t you using .NET, by the way? `:)`) Here’s what it looks like in VB6:

```
If MsgBox("Sei sicuro di voler uscire?", vbYesNo, "Sicuro?") = vbYes Then
```

Comment: +1. Also use Option Explicit On and the compiler will give you a better error message at *compile time* rather than run time. **Always** use Option Explicit On!